# adding Greek Characters to axis of bargraph

Tags: r

```
fig=bargraph.CI(x.factor=trt,response=mean,data=data[1:3,],ylim=c(0,1.5),cex.lab=0.9, cex.axis=1.0,
                names.arg=c("","",""),ylab=expression("Species Persistence ( ", phi, " )")), 
                col=c("gray30","gray","white")
segments(fig$xvals,data$mean[1:3]+data$se[1:3],fig$xvals,data$mean[1:3]-data$se[1:3])
segments(fig$xvals-.05,data$mean[1:3]+data$se[1:3],fig$xvals+.05,data$mean[1:3]+data$se[1:3])        #Add the top cap
segments(fig$xvals-.05,data$mean[1:3]-data$se[1:3],fig$xvals+.05,data$mean[1:3]-data$se[1:3])        #Add the bottom cap

box(bty="l")
legend("topright",legend="A",bty="n",inset=c(-.02,-.05))
```

I get this message after the names line:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"fig=bargraph.CI(x.factor=trt,response=mean,data=data[1:3,],ylim=c(0,1.5),cex.lab=0.9, cex.axis=1.0,
names.arg=c("","",""),ylab=expression("Species Persistence ( ", phi, " )")),"
> col=c("gray30","gray","white")
> fig=bargraph.CI(x.factor=trt,response=mean,data=data[1:3,],ylim=c(0,1.5),cex.lab=0.9, cex.axis=1.0,
+ names.arg=c("","",""),ylab=expression("Species Persistence ( ", phi " )")),

Error: unexpected string constant in:
"fig=bargraph.CI(x.factor=trt,response=mean,data=data[1:3,],ylim=c(0,1.5),cex.lab=0.9, cex.axis=1.0,
names.arg=c("","",""),ylab=expression("Species Persistence ( ", phi " )""
> col=c("gray30","gray","white")
> segments(fig$xvals,data$mean[1:3]+data$se[1:3],fig$xvals,data$mean[1:3]-data$se[1:3])
```

Comment: You should check the formatting. I removed the 'c' tag since there is no c-language content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ylab=expression(paste("Species Persistence ( ", phi, " )"))
```

instead of:

```
ylab=expression("Species Persistence ( ", phi, " )")
```

Comment: Please see @DWin's comment below about use of  "*" or "~" instead of `paste` e.g. `ylab=expression("Species Persistence ( "* phi* " )" )`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest avoiding `paste` in plotmath when possible. IMO its use inhibits useRs from understanding the proper construction of expressions:

```
 library(sciplot)
 fig=bargraph.CI(x.factor=trt,response=mean,data=data[1:3,],
            ylim=c(0,1.5),cex.lab=0.9, cex.axis=1.0,
            names.arg=c("","",""), 
            ylab=expression("Species Persistence ( "* phi* " )" ) , 
            col=c("gray30","gray","white")
                )
```

(I think you had an extra ")" in the line with `expression` and then failed to close it .)

Comment: Thanks for catching the extra braket—fixed! Just curious why you suggest avoiding `paste`?

Comment: It's often easier (as it is in this case) to use "*" or "~" as illustrated and as I said I think learning to use them adds to plotmath's "espressibility".

Answer (score 0):

This worked the best:

```
#Local Species Persistence
fig=bargraph.CI(x.factor=trt,response=mean,data=data[1:3,],ylim=c(0,1.0),cex.lab=1, cex.axis=1.0, cex.names=1.0,
    names.arg=c("","",""),ylab=expression("Species Persistence ("* italic(phi)* ")" ) , 
    col=c("gray30","gray","white")
)
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit?